# add_custom_command for a target is always executing

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

This is a simplification of another problem. But it boils down to the last `add_custom_command` (one which appends), which I want to only execute when the target `T1` is build.

However currently the problem is that every time I run `make`, the `Appending file..` command is always running.

```bash
# Fitst time running make
$ make
[100%] Creating file..
Appending file..
[100%] Built target T1

# Second time on
$ make
Appending file..
[100%] Built target T1
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(proj12 NONE)

# Phony target T1, which depends on t1.txt.
add_custom_target(T1 ALL DEPENDS t1.txt T1)

# Rule to create t1.txt dependency
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT t1.txt
    COMMAND echo "Created at `date`" > t1.txt
    COMMENT "Creating file.."
    )

# Should only execute if T1 target needs to be built.
add_custom_command(
    POST_BUILD
    TARGET T1
    COMMAND echo "Appended at `date`" >> t1.txt
    COMMENT "Appending file.."
    )
```

The cmake documentation states the following

> add_custom_command: This is useful for performing an operation before or after building the target. The command becomes part of the target and will only execute when the target itself is built. If the target is already built, the command will not execute.

So I was in the impression that the 'Appending' will only occur only when `T1` target is build (which only builds when `t1.txt` is absent).

I am just learning CMake and is confused as to how this can be done.
Do I need to create a `dummy` file for the appending to depend on?

**The original problem**

With older CMake the UseJava function `add_jar` places resource files in wrong namespace in the jar file. So my solution is to provide  `add_jar` with only `*.java` files and later will add the extra resource files using `jar` command in a CMake custom command.

The solution works and the resource files are placed properly in the jar file, but this custom command is executed every time. I want this to execute only when the jar file actually changes.

Comment: "So I was in the impression that the 'Appending' will only occur only when T1 target is build (which only builds when t1.txt is absent)" - No, building a **custom** target is not equal to building the files that the target DEPENDS from. Your target is built every time because of ALL keyword. When a custom target is building, its DEPENDS files are evaluated, and it is decided whether to rebuild them or not. But whatever decision will be, the target will be considered to be being built.

Comment: CMake [documentation for build events](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) is somehow confusing: when it tells about building the target, in case of executable/library target it means the building of the target's "main file" (creation of which is requested by `add_executable` or `add_library` call). Custom targets (created by `add_custom_target`) don't have "main file" (at least, I do not know how to define such file), so for a custom target build events are executed when the target itself is being built.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your comments, but I am still in doubt. I have added the actual problem that I am trying to solve. May be it will provide better context.

Comment: "With older CMake the UseJava function `add_jar` places resource files in wrong namespace in the jar file." - You could take `UseJava.cmake` script from new CMake, ship that script with your project and adjust [CMAKE_MODULE_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) variable. That way `include(UseJava)` will prefer the script from your project to the one shipped with the (old) CMake. While copying CMake modules usually should be avoided, I find this way nicer than attempting to "hack" existed modules.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev. That seems to be a better solution. However wonder what else could be done, in general in situations like this.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Well, I tried adding the newer `UseJava.cmake`, but the script uses functions which were added in later versions of CMake. I will have to ship the whole cascade of scripts for this to work. May be I should ditch UseJava and write something of my own. Cannot believe, how CMake can be so incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to change:

1. Remove "ALL" from target definition T1 to prevent it from building with default all targets.
2. Add one more target "default" with "ALL" parameter that caters to the default target option, this target is built by default and executes the first command to create t1.txt, the second command is executed additionally only if target T1 is explicitly specified as "make T1".

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(proj12 NONE)

# Phony target T1, which depends on t1.txt.
add_custom_target(T1 DEPENDS t1.txt)
add_custom_target(default ALL DEPENDS t1.txt)

# Rule to create t1.txt dependency
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT t1.txt
    COMMAND echo "Created at `date`" > t1.txt
    COMMENT "Creating file.."
    )

# Should only execute if T1 target needs to be built.
add_custom_command(
    POST_BUILD
    TARGET T1
    COMMAND echo "Appended at `date`" >> t1.txt
    COMMENT "Appending file.."
    )
```